# AngularJS : How do i understand $scope tree on dev tools console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have used below command in the devtools console by selecting the html element which i am intersted in , then  i was getting the $scope tree of the selected HTML element.

```
scope = angular.element($0).scope()
```

But i couldn't understand many of the items in the tree like

> eq=true, $$nextSibiling,  $$prevSibiling,  delegates,  _proto

As i go through the documents on the web, i couldn't see much documentation. Could you please help me to make me understand these concepts?

Comment: $scope is a wide concept usually you can see $parent and $child scope.

Comment: Try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: And here's a how to from ionic http://blog.ionic.io/angularjs-console/